# About Splitting Strings and ignoring trailing characters in a comparison

Tags: java, split

I am using the string.split("") of two lines and compare the strings for equality, and the problem is the resulting strings sometimes are with commas at the end and sometime are not, which gives a false negative.

```
String[] t1 = text.split(" ");
String[] t2 = str.split(" ");

for(int i=0;i<t1.length;i++)
{
    System.err.println("==============t1=====143"+t1[i]);
    for(int j=0;j<t2.length;j++)
    {
        if(t2[j].equals(t1[i]) || t2[j].equals(t1[i]+","))
        {
            x.add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the program ignores the comma if it appears?

Comment: What is the programming language? I assume it is Java, make it explicit!

Answer (score 0):

use
    java.lang.String.replace() method to replace commas before you compare strings

Comment: the problem solved: i used:

String text1 = text.replace(',', ' ');

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `java.String.matches`. There u can have regex inbetween